# How to use shared preferences here

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android and java too. Can anyone please suggest how to use shared preferences to stack history of products searched and push and remove when it reaches a certain number.

I have product list in a listview in activity1 and product details in activity2.

In activity2     context menu I want to add Add to fav  and History of searched
  products.  Once a product is added i want that fav context menu to disable. How can I stack
  history..It  is a offline app.....push and remove once the limit of history reaches.

How can I do that ..? Thank you..

Comment: see some examples on web, http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Obtain shared preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //obtain boolean value stored in preferences
    boolean booelanExample = settings.getBoolean("boolean_example", false);             
    //obtain string value stored in preferences
    String stringExample = settings.getString("string_example", "");


    //Obtain settings  editor put new values and commint again
    Editor settingsEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    settingsEditor.putString("string_example", "stringvalue");          
        settingsEditor.putBoolean("boolean_example", false);
    settingsEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain shared preferences, use the following method
In your activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long long = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).commit();
```